# LUA (ESP8266) How to call/enter a module command from a string

Tags: string, function, lua

Please forgive me, I don't even know if what I am asking is the correct terminology.

So...here goes.

I built a custom firmware of Nodemcu Dali ( from Hackerspace Stutgart.) This includes a dali lighting control "flavour" as they refer to. I had to modify it to work with the most recent LUA version. Anyway that works and the MODULE is built into the firmware.

From the LUA commandline / Interpretor (Esplorer interface, I can call the module and it all works fine.

To use the module you enter:

```
dali.arc(address_Mode,0,parameter)
```

or

```
dali.send(Address_Mode,Command,Address,parameter)
```

Address_mode can be: `dali.SLAVE , dali.GROUP`

Command can be `dali.UP_200MS , dali.IMMEDIATE_OFF , dali.GO_TO_SCENE --... about 50 commands.`

An Example command to send the light level 128 to all drivers would be as follows:

```
dali.arc(dali.BROADCAST,0,128)   -- direct arc mode ( all lights,*ignored*,50% dimmed)
```

I want to use MQTT to control this thing.
I could use MQTT topics:

```
dali_topic/arc_broadcast -- for dali.arc(dali.BROADCAST,var1,var2)
dali_topic/group -- for dali.arc(dali.GROUP,var1,var2)
dali_topic/slave -- for dali.arc(dali.SLAVE,var1,var2)
```

and my payload string would only have to 2 variables,comma seperated eg. 0,128.

This I can all do day long but now I want to make it "better"...

I want to be able to rather send the message " dali.BROADCAST,0,128" which the code should then sort into a table with elements:

```
table[1] = dali.BROADCAST
table[2] = 0
table[3] = 128
```

and call dali.arc(table[1],table[2],table[3])

The table creation works,but I cannot get dali.BROADCAST passed to the module /function? call. First off because it is a string and second because it cannot be converted to a number or whatever substitute is required.

If this can be done them the Command field could aslo be sent with the MQTT payload rather than needing 50 MQTT topics.

I suppose I could also just try a lot of if statements or search a lookup table, but perhaps there is a simple way to just insert the command field in to function/module call?

Any assistance greatly appreciated

Edit here is some LUA output:

```
table ={"dali.BROADCAST",0,128}
dali.arc(table[1],table[2],table[3])
```

result:

```
Lua error:  stdin:1: bad argument #1 to 'arc' (number expected, got boolean)
```

since if you `print("dali.BROADCAST")` you get `nil`
However

```
table[4] = dali.BROADCAST
dali.arc(table[4],table[2],table[3])
```

result works fine.

```
print( type(dali.BROADCAST ))
```

gives `number`

so how to pass my mqtt string dali.BROADCAST which is received as "dali.BROADCAST" and convert it to just dali.BROADCAST?
note I am not sending "" the message is however sent by MQTT as a CSV string.

From the Firmware source for the dali module.. in the module folder: dali.c

```
LROT_BEGIN(dali, NULL, 0)
LROT_FUNCENTRY( setup, dali_setup )
LROT_FUNCENTRY( arc, dali_arc )
LROT_FUNCENTRY( send, dali_send )
LROT_NUMENTRY( BROADCAST, BROADCAST )
LROT_NUMENTRY( SLAVE, SLAVE )
LROT_NUMENTRY( GROUP, GROUP )
LROT_NUMENTRY( IMMEDIATE_OFF, DALI_IMMEDIATE_OFF)
LROT_NUMENTRY( GO_TO_SCENE, DALI_GO_TO_SCENE)
```

The shackspace github link is the correct one, it is simply based on LUA1.45 or something low like that. I only had to modify dali.c in Modules to work with the lastest LUA.

The relevant dali files in the firmware is located in
`app/modules`
`app/include`
`app/dali`
folders

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Thinking about it, you probably always end up indexing `dali`, in which case you can do so directly by just structuring your table like this:

```lua
table[1] = "arc"
table[2] = "BROADCAST"
table[3] = 0
table[4] = 128
```

This way you can get to `dali.BROADCAST` by doing `dali[table[2]]` and to `dali.arc` by doing `dali[table[1]]`.

*HINT: You should probably still keep a whitelist of what is allowed where because someone could send any string and your program shouldn't just blindly index the `dali` table with that and return it.*

---

You probably want something like [this](https://github.com/DarkWiiPlayer/restia/blob/master/restia/utils.lua?ts=3#L47)

Here's the relevant code:

```lua
function deepindex(tab, path)
    if type(path)~="string" then
        return nil, "path is not a string"
    end
    local index, rest = path:match("^%.?([%a%d]+)(.*)")
    if not index then
        index, rest = path:match("^%[(%d+)%](.*)")
        index = tonumber(index)
    end
    if index then
        if #rest>0 then
            if tab[index] then
                return deepindex(tab[index], rest)
            else
                return nil, "full path not present in table"
            end
        else
            return tab[index]
        end
    else
        return nil, "malformed index-path string"
    end
end
```

---

Homework: this function also works with `[]` indexing for numbers, which you don't need. It should be easy to simplify the function to only do string-indexing with `.`

---

You would use that on the global environment to index it with a single string:

```lua
deepindex(_G, "dali.BROADCAST")
-- Which is the same as
_G.dali.BROADCAST
-- And, unless dali is a local, also
dali.BROADCAST
```

Keep in mind though, that this lets you remote-index `_G` with anything, which is a huge security nightmare. Better do this:

```lua
local whitelist = {}
whitelist.dali = dali

deepindex(whitelist, "dali.BROADCAST") -- this works
deepindex(whitelist, "some.evil.submodule") -- This does nothing
```

Comment: no, `string.find()` is only on the string you give it, not the entirety of `_G`.  The only reason you'd ever use that is if you didn't know where something existed.  He clearly knows where the value exists, as it's literally just `dali.BROADCAST`, but for whatever reason, the dali.arc function doesn't allow values to be passed from tables;  hence my reasoning for trying `dali.send()` instead.

Answer (score -2):

Was looking for a Wiki entry with more details, but I found none.  If you happen to know where documentation is that specifies more about the available Lua commands, please include a link in your question.

---

It appears that there may be other functions to approach the same outcome, but I'm not certain how they are worded in your particular build.

https://github.com/shackspace/nodemcu-firmware-dali/blob/master/app/dali/dali_encode.c

---

What's returned when you `print( type( dali.BROADCAST ))` ?

I was guessing it might be raw C userdata, the specific case-switch for that arc command, however, I just found a similar Lua project that lists it as hexadecimal 255

https://github.com/a-lurker/Vera-Plugin-DALI-Planet/blob/master/Luup_device/L_DaliPlanet1.lua

---

Yea, it's likely just sending hexadecimal numbers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Addressable_Lighting_Interface

try sending `dali.arc( 0xFF, 0x00, 0x80 )`
or `dali.arc( 0xFE, 0x80 )`

They make it sound like '1111 1110' ( 0xFE ) is directly followed by the brightness value, so that second command might light.

I'm not sure why it doesn't appear to be sending the correct codes when you place them in a table.  *What you've written appears to be correct*, but it's likely a one-way broadcast, so you don't receive back any error messages...

If you can't get the arc command to work with tables, possibly you'll have better luck with the dali.send() command.  Might just be a flaw in that app.  If you can't get it resolved, submit a bug report to their GitHub page.

Comment: constants like `deli.BROADCAST` are often provided for a reason and replacing them with magic numbers like `0xFE` is very bad programming style.

Comment: That **constant** hasn't changed since the 90's.

Comment: The problem with magic numbers isn't whether or not they change.

Comment: You're talking about a value that's written into C that the user can't change.  Not magic if you've defined it & have the ability to change it at any moment.  How would assigning a variable help at all?  simply put two dashes & comment beside it.  Problem solved.  That's more usable than what you're stating.  Recompiling to a new value that likely won't change until new lighting technology exists, in what, 10 years?  This value was agreed upon by practically the entire planet.  If it ever changed, that would break compatibility with how many billions of digital lightbulbs in the world?

Comment: How about you have that discussion with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) instead, because I really don't think debating the validity of decades-old programming wisdoms is relevant to this question. Magic numbers are generally understood to be worse than named constant and I pointed that out in your example. Deal with it.